# Is there any challenge-response IPSec VPN client for Linux?

Tags: network-manager, vpn

I've been looking at Network Manager and now looking at StrongSwan.   Although StrongSwan seems to support challenge-response, it seems it only does so on the server side.

Whereas vpnc/NetworkManager doesn't support it at all:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=751842

So far my options seem to be:

- forget it and use client-side certificates, managing them manually
- buy a Cisco or Juniper VPN concentrator, even though we're already using a Palo Alto

Surely there's another option?

Searching on strongswan and challenge-response, the only options seem to be server-side.   But no 2FA challenge-response clients.